# How to add a button with Tooltip, Transparent background and Glyph from code?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In XAML, you can add a button like this:

```
<Button Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="Transparent" ToolTipServie.ToolTip="Tooltip here" ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom" />
```

However I cannot achieve similar approach with C#. Assume I have a Stackpanel named "toolbar":

```
toolbar.Children.Add(new Button {
    Name = "undo",
    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe MDL2 Assets"),
    Content = "&#xE10E",
    Opacity = 100,
});
```

When I debug the code, it adds a button with squares, gray background. Also  I don't know how to add a tooltip to the button.

I tried searching for help, nothing helped. :(

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tooltip isn't a normal DP, it's an attached property via the ToolTipService class, so you need to add it as such:

```
var button = new Button
        {
            Name = "undo",
            FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe MDL2 Assets"),
            Content = "&#xE10E",
            Opacity = 100,
        };

ToolTipService.SetToolTip(button, "Tooltip here");
ToolTipService.SetPlacement(button, PlacementMode.Bottom);
toolbar.Children.Add(button);
```

Comment: I set the Content like you do, some squares just appeared instead of an Icon. Thanks for the tooltip part though, it worked. :)

Comment: Happy to help! just mark my response as the correct answer!

Comment: Thanks! It took almost 2 hours before I found it.